# Converting this function to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm working on convert this on PDO

```
function SystemConfig($str)
        {
            $tmp = mysql_query("SELECT ".$str." FROM server_status LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
            $tmp = mysql_fetch_assoc($tmp);
            return $tmp[$str];
        }
```

I tried this :

```
function SystemConfig($str)
 {
global $bdd;
            $tmp = $bdd->prepare("SELECT ? FROM server_status LIMIT 1");
            $tmp->bindValue(1, $str, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $tmp->execute();
            $tmp_res = $tmp->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $tmp_res[$str];
        }
        ?>
```

But it's return 'users_online' and not the value (10000 on the database) (PS : SystemConfig('users_online');)

Someone can help me ?
Sincerly,

Comment: How many columns in this table?

Comment: Deleting your question body is not the way to go. Just because "if anybody need it", they'd be just unable to come across this question.

Comment: OK thanks for re-edit, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function SystemConfig($str)
{
    static $row;
    global $bdd;

    if (!$row)
    {
        $stm = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM server_status");
        $row = $stm->fetch();
    }
    return $row[$str];
}
```

but better reorganize your table, because table with sole row is a nonsense

```
function SystemConfig($str)
{
    global $bdd;
    $stm = $bdd->prepare("SELECT value FROM server_status WHERE param = ?");
    $stm->execute(array($str))
    return $stm->fetchColumn();
}
```

Comment: Really, you want to select all columns just to retrieve a single value? This will not work well if you have a slow network and your DB server and your PHP server are not on the same machine.

Comment: This is why another solution proposed.

Comment: But that's a whole different table structure. whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You can only bind value parameters with PDO. You cannot bind column names, table names, or anything else.

You'd still have to manually construct this query by concatenating strings. To make cracker's life harder use a whitelisting approach:

```
if(!in_array($str, array('users_online', 'users_offline', 'free_memory')) die('...')
// rest of the function.
```

(But please, stop using the deprecated mysql_* functions. Upgrade to mysqli instead. Or use PDO, but without parameter binding for this one single query)